# How to download matplotlib for python 3.7 in windows 8?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do you download matplotlib to windows so I can use it with python?
Every other question related to this that I've found on StackOverflow has led to the same problem which is that it keeps giving me the error:

python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9gc765gs\matplotlib\

Things I have tried (from the command prompt):

pip install matplotlib

pip install matplotlib-1.5.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl (which is the file I downloaded from SourceForge and is now stored in my computer)

pip install "matplotlib-1.5.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl"

python -mpip install -U matplotlib

I even tried tried:
pip install --upgrade setuptools
python -mpip install -U pip

prior to using the other commands to make sure everything was up to date.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are having?

Comment: If you want to use matplotlib with python 3.7 you should of course not try to install any `*-cp35-*` wheel. Apart your complete setup is unclear, so I suppose there is little one can help with as it stands.

Comment: Are you using `python -mpip` or `python -m pip`? The `-m` is a parameter and should not be concatenated with `pip`. Have you had any difficulty with installing modules or packages with any other `pip` commands? You should make sure Python is in your `PATH` environment variable to run these commands from the command line, which is a checkbox option during installation. You may also need to run your command prompt at an elevated level (right click > run as admin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib has not been officially released for Python 3.7 yet.

As of this writing, a 3.7 version for Mac and Linux has been uploaded to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/#files) *earlier today*, which means the Windows versions are probably coming very soon. `pip` will probably work after that.

Similarly, no 3.7 compatible versions have been put onto [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/matplotlib/files) or integrated into the main conda repo yet. I'm sure those will be coming in the next couple of weeks.

Until then, maybe installing [from source](https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#installing-from-source) will work?

Comment: Or, if compiling freetype and libpng becomes a bit hairy, use the [unofficial binaries from Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib) to install via wheel.